# customized alert color and increase its frame depending on text input

Tags: text, colors, background, frame, uialertview

I am adding a customized alert view and want to change its color to yellow with a textview in it.For this there is a property where we pass the name of a transparent image of that color and alert picks up that color.Also i want to increase the size of alert dynamically depending on the text in textview
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

changed the color with below code .But how to dismiss alert

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlert View" message:@"hello" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:@"Close",nil];

UIImage *alertImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"plus.png"];

UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:alertImage];

backgroundImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 282, 130);

backgroundImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

[alert addSubview:backgroundImageView];

[alert sendSubviewToBack:backgroundImageView]; 
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this code to customize your uialertview..
You can take out the subviews of uialertview and can customize it any way you want.
Here is the code I used to customize the uialertivew
==========



-(void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    for(UIView *view in alertView.subviews){
        view.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    UILabel *title = [alertView valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
    title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gibson-Regular" size:15.0];
    [title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];// set title color and font

    UILabel *body = [alertView valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
    body.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gibson-Regular" size:15.0];
    [body setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];//set body color and font

    //after giving 12345 tag to your alert
    UITextView *txtBody=(UITextView*)[alertView viewWithTag:12345];
    if(txtBody){//scrollable
        txtBody.scrollEnabled = NO;
        CGRect frame  = txtBody.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        txtView.editable = NO;
        txtView.text = txtBody.text;
        txtView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gibson-Regular" size:15.0];
        [txtView setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [txtBody addSubview:txtView];
        txtBody.text=@"";

    }
    NSLog(@"%@",txtBody.subviews);
    for(UIView *view in txtBody.subviews){
        view.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
    }

    //    alertView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
}
```